# Optimizing the speed of creating new objects

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

In Yii2, executing a query through ActiveRecord

```
$banner = $site->banner;
```

is faster than using QueryBuilder

```
$banner = $this->getBanner($site->banner_id);

private function getBanner(int $bannerId): ?SimpleBanner
{
    $banner = (new Query())
        ->select(['deal_id', 'image'])
        ->from(Banner::tableName())
        ->where([
            'id' => $bannerId,
            'is_deleted' => false,
        ])
        ->limit(1)
        ->one();

    return $banner ? new SimpleBanner($banner): null;
}
```

and creating a new object from the received data

```
class SimpleBanner
{
    public int $deal_id;
    public string $image;

    public function __construct(array $banner)
    {
        $this->deal_id = (int) $banner['deal_id'];
        $this->image = $banner['image'];
    }
}
```

Most of the time is spent on creating the object. Opcache is enabled. I tried to add the class of the new object to the classmap that is created by Composer, but there was no improvement. Any ideas on how to speed up the creation of an object from a class and why ActiveRecord creates objects faster?

Comment: What takes time is executing an SQL query, not creating an object.

Comment: 0.003 for sql and 0.008 for create object. Question not about sql but about creating an object

Comment: @KirillZaytsev what YOU mean by the object? just curios

Comment: @KirillZaytsev because AR works with DB derectly, and only after that AR query DB to retrive the new object, That takes a time  0.003+0.003+time that your current network connections or whatever (localhost) browser will respond to the respond , how busy it is?, it all depends, this is a tiny configuration, you have to use more tools to exterminate this before to blame on your code